# Create subdomains like Shopify in pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django, shopify, subdomain, pythonanywhere

My domain name is 'example.com' and I need to create subdomain for every store created in that site like 'store1.examaple.com', 'store2.examaple.com'.
Code for every subdomain is the same.
currently my project is deployed on pythonanywhere and I already have custom domain.

So is it possible to dynamically create multiple subdomain in pythonanywhere same as Shopify ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On PythonAnywhere you would need separate web app for each subdomain. You could use API to create them programmatically.

Comment: can you please tell me the limit of the webapps?

Comment: Normally you can upgrade up to 40, but you can ask PythonAnywhere support for more.